# What changed in the acos function of scss?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, codepen

I tried copying this animation from codepen: https://codepen.io/davidkpiano/pen/woZNbB?editors=1111
When adding it to my js file locally, i always get this error: SassError: Undefined operation "acos(sqrt(pow(28, 2)-pow(-8, 2))/28) * 180deg".
`╷ 585 │     $angle: acos($t/($a + $b)) \* 180deg / 3.14159; │             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ╵`

I could not find any information about any changes to the acos function in scss and according to the comments, I am not the only one having this issue. I suspect it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using a newer version than when this animation was created but it might be something else. Does anybody have a fix or an idea why this is not working anymore?

Comment: What version are you using, what compiler?

Comment: I fixed it, you now have to import sqrt and pow as math.sqrt and math.pow for anyone wondering but thank you!